# Python module to control scientific instrument - error handling

Tags: python

I am writing a python module to control and read-out a scientific instrument, for example a benchtop high precision  multimeter. The instrument is connected via ethernet (peeves) and a I read and record the voltage every minute over days. Unfortunately the network is glitchy and sometimes the connection breaks down. Without any precautions, the measurement script stops and the measurement series is lost.

What is the best way to handle the errors in my module?

One way would be to catch the error with a try statement and return numpy.nan. In that way the measurement just misses one data point, but continues its execution.

Or is it better that the user deals with the exceptions?

Comment: Are you providing a timestamp along with the reading or are they periodic readings (e.g. every x seconds)?

Comment: No, that is not the functionality of the module. In the simplest way, it should just provide a measurement, for example 'instrument.readVoltage()'. I am asking if it better to return nan or raise an exception, if the connection fails.

Comment: Is a new connection made every time? If so a `NaN` or `None` might be returned and the caller can ignore the result. If you want your top level script to do something about the network problem, e.g. close and reopen the connection, you should raise an exception.

Comment: It that case, I would probably lean towards using an exception and let the user decide what they want to do when it happens.